# Import python module from a git clone in Jupyter PySpark notebook

Tags: python, git, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to clone and import a python module from a git repo using a Jupyter Pyspark notebook on Azure's HDInsight.

In the first notebook cell I successfully cloned the git repo:

```
%%sh 
mkdir ~/code
cd ~/code
git clone https://path-to-my-repo/MyRepo
```

In the next cell I try to import the module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/code/MyRepo')
import mymodule
```

This fails with:

```
ImportError: No module named mymodule
```

On further os.system('ls ...') investigation it appears like python cells run in their own environment, and files created in the %%sh cells are not accessible by the python cells.

I am looking for a way to overcome that and access my git clone from the python cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that solves this by cloning the repo from within a python cell, by running the shell commands via subprocess.check_output:

```
import subprocess
import sys
#GIT clone
subprocess.check_output('mkdir ~/code ; ~/code ; cd ~/code & git clone https://path-to-my-repo/MyRepo')
sys.path.append('~/code/MyRepo')
import mymodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/code')
from MyRepo import mymodule
```

Also check for case sensitive name mismatch

Comment: Doesn't work. From python, the ~/code doesn't exist, it's is like it runs with a different session with a different user